# What prior distributions are used in mcmcsamp() from lme4?

Tags: r, bayesian, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, prior

The `mcmcsamp()` function generates simulations from the posterior distributions of a Bayesian mixed model fitted with the `lmer()` function. What are the prior distributions? Does there exist a book or an article providing a mathematical study of the Bayesian mixed model with these priors?

Comment: Some pointers, but someone has probably some more thoughts to share: [Uniform prior in mcmcsamp](http://bit.ly/znd2BP); [lme4::mcmcsamp + coda::HPDinterval](http://bit.ly/xxyCG4).